# Rename files in a list of folders according to Folder name and custom text

Tags: r

Good day everyone,

I have a list of folders named E1 to E1000, each folder containing a bunch of random photos that are named with random messy names. I wanted each image to be named according to the folder name and customised in the following format "J_foldername_image number in the sequence. For example, if there are 5 photos in folder E1, the first photo should be "J_E1_1", the second photo should be "J_E1_2", so on and the fifth photo should be "J_E1_5".

Is there an R code to do this? Thank you very much everybody for your time!

Comment: you should add a reproducible example. does the following code help? `images = list.files("folder containing E1, E2, etc.", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE);
file.rename(images, sub("([^/]+)/([^/]+$)", "\\1/\\1_\\2", images))
`. I assume that E1, E2, etc. contain only images

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, as even without a reprex it is clearly written and has all the necessary elements (original folder names, exact desired result) for quickly providing a functional answer.

Answer (score 1):

A reprex (reproducible example) would have helped, but I guess it wasn't so easy to prepare and the question is clearly explained. Here's a suggestion. First, be sure to backup your files somewhere else, in case some irreversible loss occurs! Then, put your folders (E1 to E1000) in a folder and set the R working directory to that folder. Then try this loop:

```
folders <- list.files()
folders  # make sure this contains only the folders with files to rename!

for (fo in folders) {
  files <- list.files(fo)
  n <- 0
  for (fi in files) {
    n <- n + 1
    file.ext <- tools::file_ext(fi)
    file.rename(paste0(fo, "/", fi), paste0(fo, "/", "J_", fo, "_", n, ".", file.ext))
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark? Cheers